# Помогите Пожалуйста Найти однокоренные слова

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Однокоренные слова к слову ** ПОЛОЖИЛ** **Поиграю** **Убежал ** **Выходит
**

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что д/з.

Answer (score 1):

А в чём трудность?

ПОЛОЖИЛ- положение,приложение, переложил, заложил и др.

Поиграю- игра, игрушка,игрок, выиграть, заигрался, поиграть и др.

убежал-бег, побег,побежал, беглец,прибежал,добегался и др.

Выходит  - ход, поход,выход, заход,уходит,приходит, переход и др.